# Php parse xml (multiple nested <> </>). With one nested <> </> works, - multiple does not work

Tags: php, xml

Xml is like this:

```
<CRates>
    <Date>20010323</Date>
    <Currencies>
        <Currency>
            <ID>AED</ID>
            <Units>1</Units>
            <Rate>0.17200000</Rate>
        </Currency>
        <Currency>
            <ID>ATS</ID>
            <Units>1</Units>
            <Rate>0.04102750</Rate>
        </Currency>
    </Currencies>
</CRates>
```

Php is like this:

```
$currencies = simplexml_load_file('__joomla.xml');

/**/
$cdate=$currency->Date;
echo "<time>". $date. "</time><br>";

foreach ($currencies as $currency):
    $id=$currency->ID;
    $units=$currency->Units;
    $rate=$currency->Rate;

    echo 
    "
    <div class='id'>". $id. "</div>
    <div class='units'>". $units. "</div>
    <div class='rate'>". $rate. "</div>
    ";
endforeach;
```

If remove `<CRates> <Date>20010323</Date>` and remove ending `</CRates>`, all works.

But not removed, displays nothing.

Please, advice what need to correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `->children()` to iterate over child nodes of `Currencies`

```
$crates = simplexml_load_file('__joomla.xml');     

/**/                                               
$cdate = $crates->Date;                            
echo "<time>". $cdate. "</time><br>";              

$currencies = $crates->Currencies->children();     
foreach ($currencies as $currency):                
$id = $currency->ID;                               
$units = $currency->Units;                         
$rate = $currency->Rate;                           

echo                                               
"                                                  
<div class='id'>". $id. "</div>                    
<div class='units'>". $units. "</div>              
<div class='rate'>". $rate. "</div>                
";                                                 
endforeach;
```

Comment: You don't need to use the `children()` method, @vinodadhikary is cleaner and easier.

Comment: Yes, @vinodadhikary method is a bit shorter and less one variable, but there were missing `->Currency` in foreach statement and only now I have understood it.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is because you are accessing the `$currencies` like its the root element.  You could load the file and reference currencies with `$xmlDoc->currencies` and it should work.  Please try the following:

```
$xmlDoc = simplexml_load_file('__joomla.xml');
/**/
$cdate=$xmlDoc->Date;
echo "<time>". $cdate. "</time><br>";

foreach ($xmlDoc->Currencies->Currency as $currency):
  $id=$currency->ID;
  $units=$currency->Units;
  $rate=$currency->Rate;

  echo 
  "
  <div class='id'>". $id. "</div>
  <div class='units'>". $units. "</div>
  <div class='rate'>". $rate. "</div>
  ";
endforeach;
```

**Update:** Updated `$xmlDoc->Currencies` to `$xmlDoc->Currencies->Currency`, as we want to loop through the Currencies' children.

Comment: Sorry, but could not get to work. I simply replaced my code with the code in answer... and does not work

Comment: Seems need `foreach ($xmlDoc->Currencies as $currency):` to change to `foreach ($xmlDoc->Currencies->Currency as $currency):`

Comment: @user2465936, you're right, it is supposed to be `$xmlDoc->Currencies->Currency` since we want to loop over `Currency`.  I've updated my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$currencies = simplexml_load_file('__joomla.xml');

/**/
$cdate = $currencies->Date;
echo "<time>". $date. "</time><br>";

foreach ($currencies->CRates->Currencies->Currency as $currency):
$id    = $currency->ID;
$units = $currency->Units;
$rate  = $currency->Rate;

echo 
"
<div class='id'>". $id. "</div>
<div class='units'>". $units. "</div>
<div class='rate'>". $rate. "</div>
";
endforeach;
```

Comment: CRates is the root node so your `foreach` would fail.

Answer (score 1):

this is working fine :-

```
$xml='<CRates>
<Date>20010323</Date>

<Currencies>

<Currency>
<ID>AED</ID>
<Units>1</Units>
<Rate>0.17200000</Rate>
</Currency>

<Currency>
<ID>ATS</ID>
<Units>1</Units>
<Rate>0.04102750</Rate>
</Currency>

</Currencies>
</CRates>';
$xml1 = simplexml_load_string($xml);
//$xml hold the object iterate through as per requirement
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($xml1);
```